# How useful are geometric aspects when studying finite groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory

My newbie impression when studying finite group theory is that geometric aspects are not very prevalent. Cayley graphs play quite some role for visualising finite groups, but compared to the study of infinite groups in geometric group theory, geometric aspects seem to be marginal.

I therefore wonder:

(1) Why is geometry less interesting when studying finite groups (if this is really the case)?

(2) Could it (nevertheless) be interesting to delve into geometric group theory when studying finite groups?

I find GGT particularly interesting, but as I am currently working in finite group theory I am not sure how advisable it is to hope for connections. Finite groups are special cases of finitely generated infinite groups, but I am not sure if these are uninteresting cases from the GGT viewpoint.

Thank you for any clarifications and hints!

Comment: Does representation theory count as geometry?

Comment: I would say, yes. But somehow I don't "see" much (actually almost any) RT in the GGT texts like the ones of de la Harpe, Ghys, Bridson-Haefliger or John Meier's book "Groups, Graphs and Trees".

Comment: Hmm... do you mean that representation theory actually delivers all geometrical aspects of finite group theory? Does this then mean that for instance Gromov's theory of  hyperbolic groups -- for which finite groups are an example -- does not add anything helpful for the specific case of finite groups?

Comment: I can't imagine how you reached the conclusion that I might mean that.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry :-)

Comment: Bridson-Haefliger talk a lot about quasi-stuff. Quasi-isometry, quasi-convex, and so on. In finite groups, these just don't make sense - every finite group is quasi-isomorphic to the trivial group! (Because finite groups are virtually trivial...hehehe...) Thinking about trees (a la Meier) does not work because whenever a finite group acts on a tree there is a global fixed point.

Comment: However, have you ever come across "cyclically presented" groups? John Conway once, in, like, American Mathematical Monthly, asked if the group $\langle a,b,c,d,e; ab=c, bc=d, cd=e, de=a, ea=b\rangle$ is finite or not. An apparently "fun" problem. The solutions took three years (it is cyclic of order 11, if you are wondering). It then became a research "theme" to work out when these groups with $n$ generators were finite, and Roger Lyndon (of Lyndon and Schupp), used small-cancellation theory to prove that they are infinite for $n\geq 11$. So geometric group theory!

Comment: (Also, certain similar groups come up naturally in the study of $3$-manifolds. Look up the book "Presentations of Groups" by D. L. Johnson for more details.)

Comment: Geometry for finite groups usually means “finite geometry” and “incidence geometry”. Part of it should have the same feel, but most of it will be pretty different. “Buildings”, “Coset geometries”, and “Subgroup complexes” are all ways that geometry works in finite groups.

Comment: @user1729: Interesting hint about this Conway question! Thanks a lot also for the ref.s!

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Oh yes, I have already heard about "incidence geometries". Great hint, I'll read up this, thanks!

Comment: @Andreas You are welcome - it took me forever to find a decent reference for cyclically presented groups! Apparently there is a book of Colin M. Campbell which covers them in detail, but I could not find it. Also, there is a guy called Gerrard Williams who thinks about them these days. He perhaps puts them in a more modern, geometric context, but I cannot quite remember.

Comment: Oh, also, look up Beauville surfaces. There is a dual concept of a Beauville group, and these groups are always finite.

Comment: Tangentially, there is lots of amazing (non-GGT) geometry coming from finite subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ (and even $\operatorname{SL}(3,\mathbb{C})$); look up the McKay correspondence if you want to know more.

Comment: @Matt: Very interesting. I think that I can use this correspondence somewhere and sometime, since I play around a lot with RT on the one hand and Cayley graphs on the other. Thanks!

Comment: What the literature calls "geometric group theory" is more of an infinite groups thing.  There are other geometric things going on in finite groups though, like symmetric genus, graphs of groups on surfaces, symmetries of finite geometries, etc.

Comment: I can recommend reading the article "Subgroup complexes" by Peter Webb, pp. 349-365 in: ed. P. Fong, The Arcata Conference on Representations of Finite Groups, AMS Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics 47 (1987).

Comment: There's a book by Nathan Carter called Visual Group Theory. See http://web.bentley.edu/empl/c/ncarter/vgt/

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "geometric aspects". I think the place that your question comes from is that nobody uses the methods commonly referred to as "Geometric Group Theory" (such as those explained, for example, [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/280-2009/bhb-ggtcourse.pdf) [PDF of *A Course in Geometric Group Theory*, by Brian Bowditch), then the answer is on page 24: many of the main tools of Geometric Group Theory involve studying things up to quasi-isomorphism, and all finite groups are quasi-isomorphic to each other, so there isn't much to do.

As a secondary thing, the reason for your impression might be rather the opposite: it's not that geometric methods are less common in finite group theory, it's that other methods are more common. That is: a lot of the geometric stuff with infinite groups still works fine for finite groups, it's just rather drowned out by the significantly larger body of other tools that we can use.

However, there are very rich areas of group theory which *do* use geometric methods, interpreted more broadly. A handful have been mentioned in the comments, but I'll go for something else (mostly because it's what I know about):

Given a (finite) group $G$, if we want to study its representations, we can often have a problem of getting our hands on those representations in a form that's amenable to further study (pick any finite group whose irreducible representations are not thoroughly known, and this is likely at play there somewhere). So it can be useful to have ways to generate representations of a given group, which you can then work with.

One reasonably common way to do this is to take an action of $G$ on something that has a homology theory (for our purposes, some geometric structure $X$), compute the homology of $X$ (in the normal topological sense, with some suitable coefficients), and pass the action of $G$ on $X$ through to get an action of $G$ on the homology terms, which are modules, and therefore give you representations of $G$. As a few examples: you can take the [building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_(mathematics)) of $G$, which gives some reasonably well-understood representations, you can take the simplicial complex of the poset of the subgroups of $G$, which gives you some somewhat less well-understood groups (but give me a bit on that, I'm working on it!), or you can take some complex derived from some natural action of your group (for example, the action of $S_n$ on a set of $n$ points gives an action on the set of collections of (proper) disjoint subsets of $S_n$, which form a simplicial complex with the subsets as vertices in the obvious way, which gives you some nice representations), or you can take the subgroup complexes mentioned in the comments.